# Consulta colecciones mongo

Tags: nodejs, typescript, mongodb, express

tengo 3 colecciones Message, textMessage y location message.....estas últimas 2 "heredan" de la primera a través de un discriminator (no sé si lo hice bien jeje)...el problema es que necesito crear un endpoint que según el body (sea de texto o coordenadas de ubicación) los guarde según la colección....cuando creo el servicio y hago un save de Message(la colección madre digamos) mongo según el body va guardar y crear el registro en la colección q corresponda de las 2 hijas? Muchas gracias d antemano

```javascript
import mongoose, { Document, Schema } from "mongoose";

export interface IMessage extends Document {
    timestamp: Date;
    isReceived: boolean;
}

const options = { discriminatorKey: 'kind' };

const MessageSchema: Schema<IMessage> = new Schema({
    timestamp: { type: Date, required: true },
    isReceived: { type: Boolean, required: true }
}, options);

export default mongoose.model<IMessage>('Message', MessageSchema);

import { Schema } from "mongoose";
import Message from "./Message.model";

export interface ITextMessage {
  text: string;
}

const textMessage = Message.discriminator(
  "textMessage",
  new Schema({
    text: { type: String },
  })
);

export default textMessage;

import { Schema } from "mongoose";
import Message from "./Message.model";

export interface ILocationMessage {
  latitude: string;
  longitude: string;
}

const locationMessage = Message.discriminator(
  "locationMessage",
  new Schema({
    latitude: { type: String },
    longitude: { type: String },
  })
);

export default locationMessage;
```

Comment: Y cuál es tu pregunta? Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Dices que **el problema** es que **necesitas**, una necesidad no es un problema. ¿Qué has intentado o investigado al respecto? No sabemos nada de la estructura de tus datos y mucho menos sabemos las condiciones sobres la que operar. No podemos hacer todo por ti, no es la finalidad de [es.so]. Te invito a leer [mre]. Haz clic en [edit] y agrega lo que haga falta. Saludos

Comment: Y los discriminadores almacenan los elementos en la misma coleccion, porque esperarías que se guardaran en colecciones distintas? Si quieres colecciones distintas puedes crear modelos distintos.